# How to set SSL Certificate (FPX) to Microsoft Azure with bind domain (outside azure)

Tags: azure, ssl-certificate, pfx

**What you need to know?**

1. I am using Azure VM
2. I bind my Azure to domain that I bought from another provider outside Azure.
3. I bought SSL Certificate (goDaddy) from Azure
4. I succeeded verify SSL Certificate
5. When I exported the certificate, I got **FPX** file

**My Question**

How to upload this SSL certificate to (CPanel) my custom domain?

Comment: I'm not sure how this is azure related? if you want to put the certificate on your vm that is on azure - you need to search how to do that. vm in azure isnt any different from any other vm. should be trivial to copy file across and put it where the web server would be able to read it.